# How to Expose hidden App in Dock as it was in High Sierra?

Tags: dock, expose

When I put cursor on an app icon on Dock I can do swipe down to Expose opened windows of that app. However since Mojave it is no longer possible to Expose apps which are hidden (with Cmd+H). On High Sierra it didn't matter whether app was hidden or not - Expose has been working.

How can I enable expose on hidden apps in Dock?

Answer (score -2):

I haven't found any other option than this, although I'll be honest with me on macOS 10.16 it doesn't work. But I am sure that it will work with older versions.

Just enter **this** into the terminal here.

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -boolean yes && killall Dock
```

You can give it a try and give me your experience.

You can also undo it again no problem.

```
 defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -boolean no && killall Dock
```

**Activate Dock Exposé**

*The option shown in this example is available from Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).*

After changing the properties of the dock, the dock must be restarted.

If you want to activate the Dock Exposé (standard), you can do this as follows:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock show-expose-menus -bool yes; killall Dock
```

Comment: The OP asks "How can I enable expose on hidden apps in Dock? -- **This does not at all answer the question asked!** Do you even know what that command does? That _command_ makes an application's  **Dock** _tile_ (_app icon_), show as translucent when _windows_ of the _application_ have been hidden with e.g. **⌘H** and has no bearing or impact on allowing the hidden _windows_ of an _application_ to show in **Exposé** as the OP is wanting!

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you want? The author specifically asked how he can activate the exposure for hidden apps in the dock. I am trying to solve the problem by proposing a solution. I ask you not to be constantly eager to comment on my posts if you are of no help. If you know exactly what the problem is then answer the question instead of telling useless stuff here. Since I am the only one who tries to solve the problem so far, you should be certain that others may not have understood him exactly.